# How to sort :order nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically everytime a page loads this error pops up in the terminal. It doesn't seem to be causing any tangible issues:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass): app/controllers/habits_controller.rb:8:in `sort'
```

I want to fix it though and I have a general idea how to.

When a new habit is created instead of its `:order` defaulting to `nil` it should default to the next highest integer.

**HabitsController**

```
  def sort 
    params[:order].each do |id, order| 
    Habit.where(id: id).update_all(order: order) 
  end 
    render nothing: true 
  end

  def habit_params
    params.require(:habit).permit(
      :user_id, 
      :trigger,
      :tag_list,
      :current_level,
      :conceal,
      :missed_days,
      :target, 
      :reward,
      :comment,
      :commentable,
      :like,
      :likeable,
      :action,
      :order,
      :date_started,
      :missed_one,
      :completed,
      :completed_at,
      :notes_text,
      :notes_date, 
      :notable, 
      :note, 
      :committed => [],
      levels_attributes: [
      :missed_days,
      :days_lost], notes_attributes: [:notable, :note, :notes_text, :notes_date, :_destroy])
  end
```

**schema**

```
create_table "habits", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "order"
end
```

**rails c**

```
[2] pry(main)> Habit.last
  Habit Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "habits".* FROM "habits"  ORDER BY "habits"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Habit:0x007f94e0da39b0
 id: 12,
 missed_days: 0,
 conceal: false,
 likes: nil,
 date_started: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 00:00:00 EDT -04:00,
 trigger: "wake up",
 action: "run",
 target: "2 miles",
 reward: "eat dessert",
 user_id: 2,
 created_at: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 09:53:31 EDT -04:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 09:53:31 EDT -04:00,
 order: nil,
 completed_at: nil,
 committed: ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", ""],
 strike_date: nil,
 missed_days_date: nil>
```

**rails s**

```
Started POST "/habits/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-15 10:02:36 -0400
Processing by HabitsController#sort as */*
  User Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Habit Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 2]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('ingrain'))
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 2]]
  Level Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "levels".* FROM "levels" WHERE "levels"."habit_id" = $1  ORDER BY "levels"."id" ASC  [["habit_id", 11]]
  Level Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "levels".* FROM "levels" WHERE "levels"."habit_id" = $1  ORDER BY "levels"."id" ASC  [["habit_id", 12]]
  Level Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "levels".* FROM "levels" WHERE "levels"."habit_id" = $1  ORDER BY "levels"."id" ASC  [["habit_id", 10]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."tagger_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."tagger_type" = $2  ORDER BY taggings_count desc LIMIT 20  [["tagger_id", 2], ["tagger_type", "User"]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 2]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass): app/controllers/habits_controller.rb:8:in `sort'
```

**habit-sort.js**

```
var update_orders, update_remote_orders; 

update_remote_orders = function(orders) { 
return $.ajax({ 
url: "/habits/sort", 
type: "POST", 
data: { 
order: orders 
}, 
success: function(data) {} 
}); 
}; 

update_orders = function() { 
var orders; 
orders = {}; 
$("#sortable tr input.order:hidden").each(function(i, o) { 
orders[$(o).attr("data-id")] = i; 
return $(o).val(i); 
}); 
return update_remote_orders(orders); 
}; 

$(document).ready(function() { 
update_orders(); 
$("#sortable").sortable({ 
axis: 'y', 
handle: ".btn", 
stop: function(ui, event) { 
return update_orders(); 
} 
}); 
});
```

Comment: `params[:order]` is **nil**. Can you post the `params` that are coming?

Comment: Updated with params @Pavan

Comment: I think you can not use `order` as the column name, as it is the keyword in rails.

Comment: Try with `params[:habit][:order]`

Comment: I mean the `params` that are generated in the console log.

Comment: `When a new habit is created instead of its :order defaulting to nil it should default to the next highest integer.` -Why not use id or created_at columns for this?

Comment: @Pavan updated with params. Sorry. And do I put that line as `params[:habit][:order] = true` above line `params.require(:habit).permit(`?

Comment: `:order` is used so user can drag and drop the positioning of a habit in its list @BroiSatse

Comment: No! I mean try changing this `params[:order].each do |id, order|` to `params[:habit][:order].each do |id, order|`. And also I asked for the `params` that are coming to the `sort` method not the `Habit.last`

Comment: Oops okay. And Im shaky with console. How do i find that params for sort @Pavan

Comment: Try looking for a `params` hash in the server logs when the method `sort` is triggered.

Comment: Okay @Pavan with that new line the error changed a bit: `NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: And I updated the question @pavan with two more chunks of code. This trickier than I thought.